Relationship type in OWL
Let's say that I have two companies, and there are relationships which could occur such as conflict, competition, cooperation.
In an domain ontology, where I am dealing with universals, there can be two entities (which are connected to other entities, however the problem does not come from there), such as

Company
Relationship

And each Company can be further categorized such as Supplier, Manufacturer etc. Whilst Relationship can be further categorized such as conflict, competition, cooperation.
The problem is this: a Company and Relationship, has has_a relationship (do not confuse with the relationship which I defined within the ontology).
When I initiate the ontology for an application ontology,the structure should be like this,
Company 1 has_a conflict with Company 2.
How can I define such statement with Protege? Should I define some sort of first order logic to infer from other conditions?
Tried to just use the relationships not as an entity but as a "property", which did not resulted in what i wanted to achieve. Because each relationship also be defined, so that when query occurs whole information about the relationship also should be present.

your relationship sounds more like an n-ary relation ,how to achieve this in OWL via some intermediate nodes is documented here: https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/
